# Bootstrap Example: Loading data from JSON into a table

Tags: javascript, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to follow this Bootstrap tutorial [here](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html) and so far have the following code below. This code seems to load the HTML page OK but it does not load the data in the .json file even though the .json file is in the same directory. I am placing these files on my web server and viewing the page through Chrome but still with an empty table. The console doesn't display anything. How can I get the data1.json data to display in the table and how could I have troublshooted this?

Thank you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <table data-toggle="table" data-url="data1.json" data-cache="false" data-height="299">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap does not support the table feature you want to use. You have to include Bootstrap Table. Otherwise it won't work. Download Bootstrap table and use it in your code.
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started

Comment: Thank you - the table is loading on the page but it is still missing the data. When I put data-url = data1.json or the full https://www. path to the file on the example server I still get an error in the console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/data1.json?_=1411124131792. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: It seems cross-domain setting issue on web server side. when I try the tutorial code in local (i.e. not on wrb servet), I could see the table with data.

Comment: So could you solve the issue? I have been getting this error too.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but just in case somebody is with this issue. One of the problems of using ajax-like requests is that you need a server. Virtually any server could do, but you cannot get it working on plain filesystem.